# Error occurred while rendering the template web.frontend_layout

Tags: odoo, internal-server-error, odoo-13

After migrating ODOO Database (From 11 to 12 to 13 using OpenUpdgrade), I tried to access the application and got the following error.

```
Error to render compiling AST
AttributeError: 'website' object has no attribute 'social_googleplus'
Template: web.frontend_layout
Path: /t/html/body/div/footer/div[1]/div/div[2]/h2/a[5]
Node: <a t-att-href="website.social_googleplus" t-if="website.social_googleplus" rel="publisher">
              <i class="fa fa-google-plus-square"/>
            </a>
            
The error occured while rendering the template web.frontend_layout and evaluating the following expression: <a t-att-href="website.social_googleplus" t-if="website.social_googleplus" rel="publisher"> <i class="fa fa-google-plus-square"/> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`AttributeError: 'website' object has no attribute 'social_googleplus'`

your website now don't have field social_googleplus

This is what i get from website model on odoo 13

```
    social_twitter = fields.Char('Twitter Account', default=_default_social_twitter)
    social_facebook = fields.Char('Facebook Account', default=_default_social_facebook)
    social_github = fields.Char('GitHub Account', default=_default_social_github)
    social_linkedin = fields.Char('LinkedIn Account', default=_default_social_linkedin)
    social_youtube = fields.Char('Youtube Account', default=_default_social_youtube)
    social_instagram = fields.Char('Instagram Account', default=_default_social_instagram)
    social_default_image = fields.Binary(string="Default Social Share Image", help="If set, replaces the company logo as the default social share image.")
```

You see it, right? No more social_googleplus

Just remove that path, and everything will be ok with you